# Ravendb: map-reduce on two relating documents

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

In my ravendb I have 2 documents: Country and City

City document looks like this
Id
Name
CountryId

Country document looks like this
Id
Name

At the moment I have an index where I retrieve all cities as a list and this works.
But I would rather want to retrieve all cities grouped by countries
This is what I have

```
 public class City_ByCountry
    {
        public string CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

Map = (city => from cit in city
                            let cou = LoadDocument<Country>(cit.CountryId)
                            select new City_ByCountry
                            {
                                CityId = cit.Id,
                                CityName = cit.Name,
                                CountryName = cou.Name
                            });
```

This works but gives me a list of all cities (id, name, countryName)

But I want a list like this

CountryName [
   List with cities]

CountryName [
   List with cities]

etc

Can I do this with a reduce on the result? Or what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a reduce this is possible. See Ayende's post [Awesome indexing with RavenDB](http://ayende.com/blog/158977/awesome-indexing-with-ravendb) on how to perform advanced indexing.

I tried to modify Ayende's example to match your needs (just on Notepad, so I don't know if it even compiles):

```cs
public class City_ByCountry : AbstractIndexCreationTask<City, City_ByCountry.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public City[] Cities { get; set; }
    }

    public City_ByCountry()
    {
        Map = cities =>
                from city in cities
                select new
                    {
                        CountryId= city.CountryId,
                        CountryName = LoadDocument<Country>(city.CountryId),
                        Cities = new [] { city }
                    };
        Reduce = cities =>
                from city in cities
                group city by city.CountryId
                into g
                select new
                    {
                        CountryId = g.Key,
                        CountryName = g.First().CountryName,
                        Cities = g.SelectMany(x => x.Cities)
                    };
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at this example but it seems like this is one document. In my case I have it in two separate documents

Comment: A bit tweaking and this worked. 
One more thing. How can I also get CountryId in the Reduce statement?

Comment: I added a `CountryId`. In the reduce step all cities are grouped by the `CountryId`, you can just grap the first city to get the `CountryName`.